# Share buttons have stopped working

Tags: html, facebook, api

the share button have stoppd working (yesterday works well). The pop up open correctly when I push on share, but nothing happen when push on share (inside the popup). This is thw website http://lavozdelmuro.com/10-cosas-de-las-que-un-condon-no-te-podra-proteger-por-ejemplo-de-un-velocirraptor/

```
<!-- share meta -->
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="El mejor contenido directo a tu muro" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );?><?php echo $url; ?>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php the_permalink() ?>" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Lavozdelmuro" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="623175637741842" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100000269362837" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta content="https://www.facebook.com/Lavozdelmuro" property="article:publisher">
```

and HTML to share:

```
<a target="_blank"  href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ?> ">
    <div class="buttonFb"><span class="facebook"></span>Share Facebook</div>
</a>
```

The debugger info https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=lavozdelmuro.com

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, miss http:// here

```
<a target="_blank"  href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=**http://**<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ?> ">
    <div class="buttonFb"><span class="facebook"></span>Share Facebook</div>
</a>
```